# Are there instances of ATC services being refused to targeted pilots and/or operators?

Tags: air-traffic-control, faa

Jpe61 opines that in certain circumstances aircraft can be [denied services because of overdue fees](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/70106/20394). One service mentioned is ATC. This makes me curious if this could actually happen, since for certain airspaces ATC is federally required. (For ex., can't take off from a Class B without clearance.)

Can federally-mandated ATC services be denied in isolation (i.e. not as a result of revoking a license or permit), and, if so, are there instances of this occurring?

Comment: I think you should ask to the law stackexchange. And possibly you should carefully read the contract and term of service of the fuel operator. FAA services cannot help you to bypass existing laws (but if FAA is authorized explicitly to do so).

Comment: The question you linked concerns the UK airline Thomas Cook and EU/UK laws. To my understanding users there pay a fee for ATC services. This is not the case in the USA; over here ATC is funded primarily by taxes on airline tickets and taxes on aviation fuel, rather than a specific fee paid by the pilots/operators directly.

Comment: I don’t know how this would even be possible in the US system.  I fly out of a tower-controlled airport (that underlies a class B).  When I call and say “N12345 is ready taxi with Alpha, departing VFR northwest” they aren’t looking me up in a database, checking my registration, etc.  I could even have given a wrong tail number, or have an expired registration, or even an invalid tail number (this happened to me personally) and no one in ATC will know or care.